# Source property in event object cause rendering to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using jquery Full Calendar and run into this issue. I have two calendars in the same view. When I clicked on one event in the left calendar, it should disappear and at the same time, the same event would appear in the right calendar.

The issue is caused by the source property in the event object.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var a = {
              "id": 5,
              "color": "#2CC870",
              "title": "work",
              "name": "Helen",
              "start": "2016-07-28T14:37:00.000Z",
              "end": "2016-07-28T16:37:00.000Z",
              "_id": "5",
              "className": [],
              "allDay": false,
              "_allDay": false,
              "_start": "2016-07-28T14:37:00.000Z",
              "_end": "2016-07-28T16:37:00.000Z",
               //  "source": {
               //  "url": "/requests/employer",
               //  "className": [],
               //  "_fetchId": 1,
               //  "_status": "resolved"
                // },
            }

    $('#js-request-employer-calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',a.id);
    $('#js-request-employee-calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',a);

    console.log(calEvent);
    console.log(jsEvent);
    console.log(view);

    // change the border color just for fun
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

}
```

If I keep the source property in the event object, new events won't show up. If I hide it, it works.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour. The source property must be automatically populated.

If you're trying to add an event to a specific source, this won't be fixed, see details on the bug tracker: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2537

The only other solution would be to remove and immediately add back your event source.

Comment: so you are saying because it has to be automatically populated, the event object with source property can't just be transferred from one calendar to another?       I eventually just used delete to delete the source property before transferring and it worked. But it's good to know why this isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, have you tried fetching the client event using the clientEvents method or just using the calEvent provided in this function? See this demo - the event is copied and moved to +3 days (although within the same calendar). http://plnkr.co/edit/lDHhdkGWyhE9yR4BHtzy?p=preview // or another link with eventClick: http://plnkr.co/edit/N1Qjg6dkVQPqwiUnP3Bn?p=preview

Comment: yeah i think the example just used different ways to fetch the event object. but not sure it will work in another calendar. Thanks for the help.